# how to make redirect in webrick/ruby?

Tags: ruby, redirect, webrick

How to make Redirect in WEBRICK Ruby, can the simplest example with the syntax?

In this example

```
require 'webrick'

    class MyServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
        def do_GET (request, response)
                result = ""           
                case request.path
                    when "/redirect_test"
                          puts("not yet working")
                    when "/test"
                        result = " arg"
                    when "/"
                else
                result = " error"
                end
            response.body = "main"+result
        end
    end
    server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 1234)
    server.mount "/", MyServlet
    server.start
```

Comment: See [`WEBrick::HTTPResponse#set_redirect`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPResponse.html#method-i-set_redirect)

Comment: @Stefan Example can be?

Comment: `response.set_redirect(WEBrick::HTTPStatus::TemporaryRedirect, "/some/url")` should work.